# How to select a graph in graph editor

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, nla-editor, dopesheet, graph-editor

I am doing an animation and in graph editor i need to interpolate some graphs. I select the graph point by point but it is not comfortable. Is there any shortcuts to select the graph? 
[image: graph editor]

Answer (score 3):

To select a single "curve" in the graph editor, select a point and hover over it and hit <kbd>L</kbd> to select all the points, hit <kbd>A</kbd>. To select an area of points, hit <kbd>B</kbd> and use the box select tool.